# No images after installation Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2

I installed the latest version of magento 2.2.2

After this no images displayed and JS no works.

I run some commands but still not work.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

next:

```
delete folder pub/static without .httaccess
```

and in app/etc/di.xml change line:

```
symlink to copy
```

Still not work

[image]

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f this command working or not.

Comment: Command working but after this no result.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already done that then can you check the permission of Pub and Var folder. Set the permission to 777 recursive.

Another reason can be lack of memory. Try increasing the site of memory in PHP to see if that works for you!